# MobX + React Native: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I have an old project which I pushed the last commit a year ago. When I run my React-Native project, I see "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.".

[image]

But if I enable debugging using the Chrome browser, it works.
How can I fix this?
FYI, I have to fix this issue without increasing the react-native version.
If I install a newer react-native, I see tons of other issues.

Thanks

```
Yarn: 1.22.19
```

package.json

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"mobx": "^6.6.1",
"mobx-persist-store": "^1.0.6",
"mobx-react": "^7.5.2",
"typescript": "~4.0.0",
```

Comment: Any updates on that?

Comment: @AlexLvovsky Not yet.